# How to identify the data transfer between region to region in s3 using access log?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following sample access log message.

I am sure that I can identify the data transfer between region to region in the access log message.

For example, `APN1-APN2-AWS-Out-Bytes` means that the data transfer occurred from `APN1` to `APN2`.

Below is my sample message.

```
{"BucketOwner":"myowner","Bucket":"bucketname","Date":"[19/May/2023:23:00:12 +0000]","RemoteIp":"15.xxx,xxx","Requester":"arn:aws:sts::947146334561:xxxxx/xxxx/i-098f420186fe97103","RequestId":"YZAJRWNXVHTYQEBN","Operation":"REST.GET.OBJECT","Key":"xxxxxx","RequestURI":"xxx","HTTPStatus":"200","ErrorCode":"-","BytesSent":0,"ObjectSize":8803940,"TotalTime":19,"TurnAroundTime":"-","Referer":"\"-\"","UserAgent":"xxxxx","VersionId":"-","HostId":"xxxxx/fTebusD5pNg4Dy9W7nHx/OhSfRywTs40PA==","SignatureVersion":"SigV4","CipherSuite":"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","AuthenticationType":"AuthHeader","HostHeader":"xxxxx","TLSVersion":"TLSv1.2","AccessPointArn":"-"}
```

I think that the `operation` field indicates the method but it just shows the `GET` or `PUT` so I cannot know the destination is another region or the current region.

Is there a way to identify the data transfer for other region using access log?

Comment: One way is to look up `RemoteIp` in the AWS IP list (Google for it). The other way is to use `Requester` to look up the associated `AssumeRole` in CloudTrail, but (1) that won't work if it's not a CloudTrail account that you control, and (2) you'll need to ingest CloudTrail events into a search engine to support cross-region or cross-account searches.

Comment: `RemoteIp` is a good choice but it is frequently updated so that the ip addr is different every update? If so, maintaining job might be required. It is a little bit complex.

Comment: :shrug: if you want to perform the analysis, you need to use the data available. You won't find a billing-specific concept such as inter-region data transfer in an access log.